# iOS: MPMusicPlayerController setting volume is laggy

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, uislider, mpmusicplayercontroller

When setting the volume using the `AVAudioPlayer` to play sound I´v found it necessary to also adjust the `MPMusicPlayerController` accordingly, else the max volume of the `AVAudioPlayer` will be that which the iPhone is set to initially (i.e via it´s buttons). Doing it this way brings up the Volume HUD which shows the volume (I´v hidden that since the slider shows the volume, and that´s enough) But the problem is `laggy` controls. Sometimes the slider is just a little lag and other times it can be really choppy to the point it´s non-usable. This happens when I connect it up to the `MPMusicPlayerController`. Is there another way of doing it, or a fix for this?

```
- (IBAction)volumeSliderMoved:(UISlider *)sender
{
      // self.player is of type AVAudioPlayer
      self.player.volume = [sender value];
     [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setVolume:[sender value]];
}
```